# NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM VS DOMAIN\Machine$

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

Here is what happened. I run a web application on windows server 2008 R2. The app pool it uses runs under LocalSystem account. The application complained about "NT Authority\SYSTEM" not having access to my database, so i added that user to the database. It all worked fine until yesterday, when the application started complaining about "Development\MyMachineName$" not having access to my database. The app pool still is running under "LocalSystem" account. I am confused why is it now changed the identity.

While playing around i ended up removing my username from sql server security. My sql server 2012 instance is running in windows authentication mode. now i cant connect to the sql instance. to fix this found someone suggested to use "psexec -i -s ssms" to launch management studio under "NT Authority\System" account. when i tried this the management studio tries to log on with "Development\MyMachineName$" as well. i am now wondering what happened to "NT Authority\SYSTEM" identity.

Thanks in advance for the upcoming help :)

EDIT:
My SQL Server instance is on same machine as the web application. i.e. its a dev machine where is have iis and sql server running for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of stuff going on here, so hopefully this will clarify things for you.

> I run a web application on windows server 2008 R2. The app pool it
>   uses runs under LocalSystem account. The application complained about
>   "NT Authority\SYSTEM" not having access to my database, so i added
>   that user to the database.

If the database server is local to the IIS server, that's fine (though I would still use a domain account to run the app pool). If the database server is remote from the IIS Server then the "local system" pool with attempt to authenticate a network resource which will transition to using the computer account Domain\Computer$ (as would network service).

> It all worked fine until yesterday, when the application started
>   complaining about "Development\MyMachineName$" not having access to my
>   database. The app pool still is running under "LocalSystem" account.

I can't tell from your question if these are the same server or not, more clarification would be needed.

> While playing around i ended up removing my username from sql server
>   security. My sql server 2012 instance is running in windows
>   authentication mode. now i cant connect to the sql instance. to fix
>   this found someone suggested to use "psexec -i -s ssms" to launch
>   management studio under "NT Authority\System" account. when i tried
>   this the management studio tries to log on with
>   "Development\MyMachineName$" as well. i am now wondering what happened
>   to "NT Authority\SYSTEM" identity.

NT Authority\System is a special built in identity and does not traverse network resources, if it needs to it auths as the computer account Domain\Computer$. I don't know the whole setup from your text but for the psexec to work, it'd have to start ssms on the database server or it will continue to use the computer account. If you need access back, be a member of the server admins windows group and start SQL Server up in single user mode - connect with windows authentication (locally) and add your login back in.

We'd need a infrastructure diagram to get more into it, but the basics are:

1. Built in identities and accounts can't authenticate on a network unless they use the computer object.
2. Built in identities and accounts are only good for the server they are on and local to.
3. Giving permissions to anyone who could access that computer (through the computer object) is grossly over-provisioning permissions.
4. If you are running an application, the identity if yours so you could have been authenticating with your account the whole time testing. While individual threads can have different identities, most applications inherit the identity that spawned the process and in this case is most likely yours.

Comment: Thanks for the nice response. My SQL Server instance is on same machine as the web application. i.e. its a dev machine where is have iis and sql server running for development. so still wondering whey its trying to connect to database as computer account where it was fine before today.

Comment: At this point I'd have to look at how the security is setup and the errorlog of the instance. Otherwise the details need to be filled in a bit more. Double checking the connection strings used, app pool identity, iis identity, sql server logins and permissions, etc. It sounds like it should work from what you've said, but it doesn't, hence the extra investigation needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured it out. The reason was that when connection string uses computer name then it forwards "MACHINE$" as identity but when it is using localhost then it forwards "SYSTEM" as identity.